# JavaScript Regex to Capture a String in a Pattern and Replace it with a New String but Only for Specific Lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an ASP.NET Core project where I use Gulp to compile and minify resources such as LESS, CSS, TypeScript and JavaScript. I'm converting the JavaScript to be modules based, but I'm running into a small issue with the TypeScript to JavaScript conversion. In TypeScript I reference other modules like this:

```
import * as test2 from "./Test2";
```

But in JavaScript, this line has to be converted to:

```
import * as test2 from "./Test.js"
```

Notice the difference in the file reference. In JavaScript I have to provide the `.js` extension or the browser will not load it.

I decided to add a replace task into my Gulp pipeline to look for any lines that start with `import`, find their file reference and replace it with a new reference that adds the extension. I have come up with this regex that captures the `"./Test2`, but I want to constrain it only look at lines that start with `import` and I'm not sure how to do that. Here's my current regex:

```
/(".\/w+)/gm
```

Here's a [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/WZaaeA/2) of the expression, test string, and end result. What should I do to enhance the regex and constrain it to only lines that start with `import` so that it doesn't wrongfully affect any other potential lines that should stay as they are? I'd appreciate any examples since my knowledge of regex' is limited.

Comment: *"only lines that start with `import`"* -> `/^import...`?

Comment: I thought of that too, but it didn't work, but I'm obviously making a mistake. Look at the linked RegEx101.

Comment: That's not what you said you're working with in the question, but... *is* the word import immediately followed by a "? Read the explanation in Regex101, I'm not sure what's unclear.

Comment: I'm working on the "reopen" queue and was about to vote to re-open your question because you provided more detail until I saw all that extraneous 'protest' nonsense nobody in the world in general wants or needs to see or know about. That's NOT how stackoverflow works. If you want to discuss issues about members and practices, go to stackoverflow META site. Q & A here are expected to be clear, focused, to the point and TECHNICAL *ONLY* to benefit others who are trying to solve a specific technical problem. Your disputes with others here are uniteresting or worse. Not voting to reopen.

Comment: If you want to go a *little* out of the bounds of the technical (a *little*) stick to the comments below the question or answer. Not *in* the question or answer section which is supposed to exhibit only the technical part of the question or answer. Otherwise people will quickly lose patience with the question/answer and/or you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like that : https://regex101.com/r/Qwy2a1/1

regex : `^import([^"]*)"([^"]*)";?`

substitution : `import $1"$2.js";`

with : `import * as test2 from "./Test2";` that return `import  * as test2 from "./Test2.js";`

Comment: Link-only answers are **not** useful: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/248731

Comment: @Ant697, thanks for showing an example. It works for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to capture the string between the double quotes. This regex will do that:

```
^import[^"]*"(.+)";
```

If you know that the final semicolon will assert the end of the string, you should add a **$** to the end of the regex for sanity (nothing can exist behind it in the input string and still return a match).

Comment: The problem with your expression is that it matches the whole string, where I want to preserve most of it and only replace the `"./Test2"` with `"./Test2.js"`.

Comment: It matches the whole string as was your requirement. The string has to start with the string 'import'. Which part of the string you would like to capture (if any) is unclear. My solution is an assumption which captures './Test2' or './Test2.js', as per your example.

Comment: @Gup3rSuR4c 'replace' is not mentioned anywhere in your question title. Which function will you use to make this replacement and in which programming language will you do it? You should add tags for this.

As your input string is so simple, you may actually be looking for a way to concatenate substrings.

Comment: @Gup3rSuR4c My answer perfectly answers your initial question. Your question title (and possibly body) should be modified to reflect what data you actually want to retrieve.